# Error while refreshing pending block on main: Post http://127.0.0.1:8545: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8545: getsockopt: connection refused

Tags: go-ethereum, ether

i have this problem :

Error while refreshing block template on main: no mining work available yet

https://github.com/sammy007/open-ethereum-pool/issues/387

this dident help

https://github.com/sammy007/open-ethereum-pool/issues/76

any of the great developers here can help me

with all of respect for all of you guys

Features
This pool is being further developed to provide an easy to use pool for Ethereum miners. This software is functional however an optimised release of the pool is expected soon. Testing and bug submissions are welcome!

Support for HTTP and Stratum mining
Detailed block stats with luck percentage and full reward
Failover geth instances: geth high availability built in
Modern beautiful Ember.js frontend
Separate stats for workers: can highlight timed-out workers so miners can perform maintenance of rigs
JSON-API for stats
Proxies
Ether-Proxy HTTP proxy with web interface
Stratum Proxy for Ethereum
Building on Linux
Dependencies:

go >= 1.9
geth or parity
redis-server >= 2.8.0
nodejs >= 4 LTS
nginx
I highly recommend to use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

First install go-ethereum.

Clone & compile:

git config --global http.https://gopkg.in.followRedirects true
git clone https://github.com/sammy007/open-ethereum-pool.git
cd open-ethereum-pool
make
Install redis-server.
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I splitted up the processes for the open ethereum pool to:
- api
- miner
- unlocker
- payment

and actually I get the same errors on the miner process: 
2018/09/12 22:32:06 Error while refreshing block template on main: no mining work available yet
2018/09/12 22:32:06 Error while refreshing block template on main: no mining work available yet
2018/09/12 22:32:06 Error while refreshing block template on main: no mining work available yet
2018/09/12 22:32:06 Error while refreshing block template on main: no mining work available yet
2018/09/12 22:32:06 Error while refreshing block template on main: no mining work available yet
2018/09/12 22:32:06 Error while refreshing block template on main: no mining work available yet

Actually what's strange is that the system was already running with the given configuration. I'm further investigating and once I have something I sure will try to share it.

Answer (score 0):

`geth console --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --mine`